# Register user biometrinc finger print in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, biometrics, android-biometric

Can we register a biometric fingerprint on the phone in flutter. I search about that on google and found [loca_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) flutter plugin but it can only get the list of biometric fingerprints and authenticate fingerprint but what I need is to register biometric fingerprints in the device.

Answer (score 5):

Third party apps do not have the capacity to register/add biometric materials to devices, no matter what platform you are using -- flutter, etc. Here is how the flow works in general.

1. User gets a new phone (purchased, gifted, found, etc.), a phone that supports biometric authentication.
2. User goes to Settings and enrolls a biometric template (e.g. enrolls their fingerprint as a way of unlocking the device). In general, this is the only way to register/enroll a fingerprint/face/iris/etc.
3. Your app wants users to authenticate using biometrics and so implements something similar to what's described [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd) or [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html).

Now inside your app, when the user clicks to `authenticate()`, your app never actually sees any biometric materials. Biometric materials are kept in a secure location so that third party apps cannot access them. What your app gets is acknowledgement from the Framework that the fingerprint/face/iris trying to authenticate into your app is indeed enrolled on the device. Checkout the blog posts I mentioned for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this. Just take a look at this:
[Fingerprint Authentication in Flutter](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fingerprint-authentication-in-flutter/)

Accordingly you also need to set permissions in android manifest file too.

Comment: this blog is about to get the registered fingerprint and validate fingerprint but I need to add a new biometric fingerprint to the device.